# How to automate clicks using Selenium (Java) for elements within div with higher z-index

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, z-index

I have a div with higher z-index and it appears as a modal, how do I make selenium interact with the buttons within that modal.

CSS:

```
.buX {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 504px;
    z-index: 501;
    height: 556px;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 580px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="buX" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-labelledby=":7c" 
  style="left: 115.5px; top: 28.5px;">
    <div class="buX-K7">
      <button name="welcome_dialog_next" class="J-at1-auR">Next</button
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Chrome Webdriver and Java

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more details? Share your code and exception log

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and the HTML you have shared as the element is within a *Modal Dialog Box* to invoke `click()` on the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.buX button.J-at1-auR[name='welcome_dialog_next']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='buX']//button[@class='J-at1-auR' and @name='welcome_dialog_next'][contains(.,'Next')]"))).click();
  ```